# DocuSign Signature Remove ID

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to set up signatures in such a way as to not have the ID displayed in the resulting signature image ?

Example Image:

[image]

I want the ID (6356 ) below the signature removed , is it possible to do this using the API ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Log into your account via the web console
Click **Go To Admin** -> **Signing Settings**

[image]

DocuSign Support Article: [DocuSign eSignature Admin Guide - Configure Signature Adoption Options](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=dqc1583277355406.html&_LANG=enus)